# Get maximum nesting of tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a way, given a BeautifulSoup-parsed document, to find what the maximum level of nesting is.

E.g. I need `magic_function` in:

```
r = requests.get("http//example.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
depth = magic_function(soup)
```

Which, for, e.g., this document, would return 4:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
            <strong>Some Text.</strong>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some ideas I've had:

1. Is there a function in BeautifulSoup to do this? Looking at docs and Googling has availed me nothing.
2. Is there another library that would allow me to do this? Again, Googling has availed me nothing, but I may simply not know what to search for.
3. Should I try just traversing the tree with a function I've built on my own? I'd really rather not, but I could certainly do that.

Comment: In your example, html only has 1 child, body only has 1 child and p only has 1 child. What should be the output if html has 3 children and body has 15 children?

Comment: I've amended my example; it shouldn't change the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traversing the tree with your own `magic_function()` isn't difficult.  You could use a simple recursive function like:

```
def magic_function(soup):
    if hasattr(soup, "contents") and soup.contents:
        return max([magic_function(child) for child in soup.contents]) + 1
    else:
        return 0
```

You would want to call the function using the document's top-level `html` tag so that it doesn't count the nesting within the `soup` object as a nesting level.

Using your above document structure, this function call returns `4`:

```
>>> magic_function(soup.html)
4
```

Comment: Sounds good! To be clear, though, there is not a function of this nature included in the module?

Comment: I don't believe this is a common ask.  Most people use BS for scraping information *contents* out of a web page.  I don't know how many are interested in the maximum nesting depth.

Comment: Ah, I see; the idea is to abstract away the HTML, not focus on it?  Anyway, your answer solves my problem, so I'll accept it.

Comment: I would say the idea is to use the HTML structure to navigate and extract information from the page.  I guess my comment was more people (it seams to me) use Beautiful Soup to navigate and extract the content from a page or document rather than to analyze the structure of a document - but it certainly is a perfectly valid use case.  :-)